# Firebase AppCheck token always null

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.android, token, firebase-app-check

I'm having this issue since one week on a Xamarin Android application.
I get the token with this method:

```
public async void GetToken()
{
 var AppCheckToken =  await AppCheck.GetToken(false);

            if (AppCheckToken is AppCheckTokenResult Tok)
            {
                string r;
                r = Tok.Token;
                Preferences.Set("AppCheckToken", r);
            }
}
```

that always return this string `eyJlcnJvciI6IlVOS05PV05fRVJST1IifQ==` on both debug and physical (production) mode. I also tried to make internal tests in Play Console and then download the app from there, but result is always the same.

Here's how I initialize AppCheck:

```
        auth = FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(app);
        PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory f = new PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory();
        f.Create(app);
        AppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.GetInstance(app);
        AppCheck.InstallAppCheckProviderFactory(f);
        AppCheck.SetTokenAutoRefreshEnabled(true);
```

I noticed also that AppCheckToken variable declared in GetToken() method is always null and returns this FirebaseException:

> --- End of managed Firebase.FirebaseException stack trace --- com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: null at
> com.google.firebase.appcheck.internal.DefaultFirebaseAppCheck.lambda$getToken$1(DefaultFirebaseAppCheck.java:205)
> at
> com.google.firebase.appcheck.internal.DefaultFirebaseAppCheck$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.then(Unknown
> Source:0) at
> com.google.android.gms.tasks.zze.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:1)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942) at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
> android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7892) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) Caused
> by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null at
> java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:699) at
> java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:861) at
> com.google.firebase.appcheck.playintegrity.internal.PlayIntegrityAppCheckProvider.lambda$getPlayIntegrityAttestation$4$com-google-firebase-appcheck-playintegrity-internal-PlayIntegrityAppCheckProvider(PlayIntegrityAppCheckProvider.java:105) at
> com.google.firebase.appcheck.playintegrity.internal.PlayIntegrityAppCheckProvider$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.then(Unknown
> Source:4) at
> com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzo.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:1)
> ... 8 more

I tried also to generate a debug token from Firebase Console to use in the app in debug mode but when I make the call to Firebase Storage (that is already enforced) it keeps saying "AppCheck Token is invalid".

**UPDATE**:
I've tried also this approach: `FirebaseAppCheck AppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.Instance; AppCheck.InstallAppCheckProviderFactory(PlayIntegrityProviderFactory.Instance);`
and for just one time FirebaseException was saying something like "PlayStore is not uptodate in your device". So I've updated PlayStore and now it throws the same error described above. I've tried to get the token with an `AddOnSuccessListener(this)` but result is the same.
Also I have to tell that `var AppCheckToken` declared before the if statement becomes always an object of class DefaultFirebaseAppCheckTokenResult.
I don't know what else to do...

IMHO there's a problem with declaration of objects (that are nulls), but since there aren't documents on how to use AppCheck on C# I'm screwed.

Comment: You can try to update all the Firebase related libraries to the latest version and try again.

Comment: I've updated all of them, excepts Xamarin.Firebase.Auth that throws an error of dependencies with AndroidX.Browser. Anyway Authentication works well, and Xamarin.PlayIntegrity.AppCheck and Xamarin.PlayIntegrity.AppCheck.Interop are always up to date

Comment: I've tried also this approach: FirebaseAppCheck AppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.Instance; AppCheck.InstallAppCheckProviderFactory(PlayIntegrityProviderFactory.Instance); and for just one time FirebaseException was saying something like "PlayStore is not uptodate in your device". So I've updated PlayStore and now it throws the same error described above.

Comment: You can try to reinstall your app and restart your mobile.

Comment: No ways, unfortunately

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issues and found the following worked for me. Issue was that in debug the result of the AppCheckTokenResult is different type to what you will receive in the release version. My method to retrieve the token simply added one further type check to account for this.

```
public async Task<string> GetAppCheckToken()
{
    var appCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.GetInstance(_firebaseApp);
    var token = string.Empty;
    var appCheckToken = await appCheck.GetAppCheckToken(false);
    
    if (appCheckToken is AppCheckTokenResult Tok)
    {
        token = Tok.Token;
    }
    else if (appCheckToken is DefaultAppCheckToken defaultToken)
    {
        token = defaultToken.Token;
    }

    return token;
}
```

The `DefaultAppCheckToken` is found in the Firebase.AppCheck.Internal namespace so you need to include the following at the top of the file `using Firebase.AppCheck.Internal;`

For clarity I set my firebase config for app check the following way

```
var firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(activity);

// Get an instance of FirebaseAppCheck
FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.GetInstance(firebaseApp);

// Continue with Firebase AppCheck initialization
#if DEBUG
firebaseAppCheck.InstallAppCheckProviderFactory(
    DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.Instance);
#else
firebaseAppCheck.InstallAppCheckProviderFactory(
    PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory.Instance);
#endif
```